# Extract part of a string before and after a word using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have a long text, and I wanna cut it in a way to have a specific keyword, 5 words before and 5 words after that keyword. The keyword contains some special characters, how can I do it via preg_match in PHP?

I wanna search for {query:some_text_goes_here:some_number_goes_here} pattern. A sample would be:

```
{query:this is a test:123456}
```

So considering the following is the text:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam posuere efficitur. Maecenas interdum sem massa, eu tincidunt dolor lacinia quis. Fusce faucibus odio urna, eu consectetur enim congue in. Cras id neque nec urna pellentesque {query:this is a test:123456} feugiat. Etiam ut elit sed lectus tempor fringilla. Nullam metus lectus, ullamcorper eget interdum eu, volutpat convallis augue. Ut pretium accumsan felis a placerat. Aenean aliquam orci quis elementum tincidunt
```

My desired return is:

```
id neque nec urna pellentesque {query:this is a test:123456} feugiat. Etiam ut elit sed
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use preg_match like this in php

```
(?:\w+\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,4})?({query:this is a test:123456})(?:\W+\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,4})
```

so you can combine into something like this

```
preg_match('/(?:\w+\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,4})?({query:this is a test:123456})(?:\W+\w+(?:\W+\w+){0,4})/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/3fViv) of both.

Here's a `preg_replace` replacing all with capture groups `1` and `3`:

```
$keyword = preg_quote('{query:this is a test:123456}');
$text = preg_replace("/.*?(([^ ]+ ){5})$keyword (([^ ]+ ){5}).*/", '$1$3', $text);
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Uafcq2/1) and graphic:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iLBavauRZRInS9L-)

Here's a `preg_match` using capture groups `1` and `3` from the match:

```
$keyword = preg_quote('{query:this is a test:123456}');
preg_match("/(([^ ]+ ){5})$keyword (([^ ]+ ){5})/", $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1].$matches[3];
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Uafcq2/2) and graphic:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RH7H5bK00aiho0zq)

Comment: That's great, thanks!
But I have another concern, if the keyword attached to a comma, dot, etc, it won't match, like:
pellentesque {query:this is a test:123456}, feugiat. Etiam
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Another question, what if there is more than one occurrence for the keyword? How can I capture both of them?